# Pyspark 2.6 How increase a value column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm training in Pyspark using the cloudera virtual machine that is coming with Python 2.6.
I read already the file in a RDD. I need to increase the number in one of the file columns.

structure file:

```
student,grade
Owen,4
Andres,3.9
Leidy,4
Flor,5
Jhon,4
Paola,3.8
```

My code to read the file is already working and showing up the data as below:

code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

#Context-definition

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('local')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

grades_report = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/input/family_grades.txt")

grades = grades_report.map(lambda x: x.split(','))

print(grades.collect())
```

It's printing:

[image]

Now I need to increase the column grade  in 2, then I added the code:

```
header = grades_report.first()
grades = grades_report.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
grades_incr = grades.filter(lambda x: x != header).map(lambda x : int(x[1]) + 2)
print(grades_incr.take(2))
```

This approach doesn't work because it's not mapping the columns as I expect and the error I'm getting is:

```
  File "/home/cloudera/scripts/spark0123.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    grades_incr = grades.filter(lambda x: x != header).map(lambda x : int(x[1]) + 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'grade'
```

Please someone has an idea? I think my filter is not working right.
thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

### DataFrame Approach

```py
grades = spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv('file.txt')
print(grades.collect())
grades_incr = grades.select(grades['student'], grades['grade'] + 2)
print(grades_incr.take(2))
```

### RDD Approach

```py
grades_report = sc.textFile('file.txt')
grades = grades_report.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
header = grades.first()
grades_incr = grades.filter(lambda x: x != header).map(lambda (_, grade): float(grade) + 2)
```

Comment: this approach sounds good. If you should use map and filter function what might you do?  thanks

Comment: @AndresAngel I updated the answer : ) the RDD approach should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you extract the header before you split on `,`. You could change it to:

```
grades = grades_report.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
header = grades .first()
grades_incr = grades.filter(lambda x: x != header).map(lambda x : float(x[1]) + 2)
```

And I belive the `int` cast should be a `float` since you have doubles.